# Pandas Concatenation not working properly

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

So I've been setting up a label archive on my deep learning classifier and I wanted to concatenate the labels of an already existing 2D archive into one I just made.

The one that exists is 'y_trainvalid' (39209, 43), which stands for 39209 images in 43 classes. The new label archive I'm trying to add is 'new_file_label' (23, 43). On these archives, the number set to 1 if it matches the class and 0 if it doesn't.
Here's a sample of both of them:

```py
print(y_trainvalid)
print(new_file_label)

       0    1    2    3    4    5    6   ...   36   37   38   39   40   41   42
0     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9     0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
11    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
12    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
13    0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
14    0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
15    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
16    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
17    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
18    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
19    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
21    0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
22    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
23    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
24    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
25    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
26    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
27    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
28    0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
29    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
4380  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4381  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4382  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4383  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4384  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4385  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4386  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4387  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4388  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4389  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4390  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4391  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4392  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4393  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4394  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4395  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4396  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4397  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4398  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4399  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4400  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4401  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4402  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4403  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4404  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4405  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4406  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4407  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4408  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4409  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

[39209 rows x 43 columns]
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...   36   37   38   39   40   41   42
0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
13  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
14  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
15  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
16  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
17  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
18  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
19  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
20  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
21  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
22  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

[23 rows x 43 columns]
```

When I tried to concatenate using this command:

```py
y_trainvalid2 = pd.concat([y_trainvalid, new_file_label], ignore_index=True)
```

Something like this appeared:

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...   41   42    5    6    7    8    9
39204  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39205  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39206  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39207  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39208  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39209  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39210  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39211  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39212  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39213  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39214  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39215  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39216  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39217  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39218  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39219  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39220  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39221  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39222  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39223  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39224  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39225  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39226  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39227  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39228  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39229  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39230  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
39231  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

As if it doubled the amount of columns to fit the data instead of putting the new data just below it. I'm not sure why this is happening cause I'm pretty sure both label archives have the same number of columns.

When I print use the 'y_trainvalid2.head().to_dict()' command, this appears:

```
{0: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '0': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 1: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 10: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '10': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 11: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '11': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 12: {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '12': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 13: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '13': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 14: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '14': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 15: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '15': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 16: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '16': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 17: {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '17': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 18: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '18': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 19: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '19': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 20: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '20': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 21: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '21': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 22: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '22': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 23: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '23': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 24: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '24': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 25: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '25': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 26: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '26': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 27: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '27': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 28: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '28': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 29: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '29': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 3: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 30: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '30': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 31: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '31': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 32: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0},
 '32': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 33: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '33': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 34: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '34': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 35: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '35': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 36: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '36': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 37: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '37': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 38: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0},
 '38': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 39: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '39': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 4: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 40: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '40': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 41: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '41': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 42: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '42': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 5: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '5': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 6: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '6': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 7: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '7': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 8: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '8': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 9: {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 '9': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you try `y_trainvalid2 = pd.concat([y_trainvalid, new_file_label]`? Please give us a sample of your initial data frames ;)

Comment: When I try y_trainvalid2 = pd.concat([y_trainvalid, new_file_label] the problem stays the same, but the last index numbers change to 0 till 22. I'll edit the original dataframes

Comment: this is not possible, you haven't the same column names in the both data frames ?

Comment: Can you hard code two small (e.g., 5x5) dataframe that demonstrate this problem and used those in your examples? The current examples are, uh, overwhelming to say the least.

Comment: A sample of your initial data, is for us … In order to reproduce your issue. You print your data frames but the most interesting is to copy/paste your sample to work. Here it is not possible for me to work on your data :)

Comment: The existing dataframe go from column 0 to column 42, so I build a dataframe with the same columns expecting it appear below once I concatenate

Comment: one moment. just do `df.head().to_dict()` to extract a sample of your data frame and gives that in your post.

Comment: I think your column names are really different. You need maybe to try to concatenate the same `y_trainvalid` data frame with `pd.concat([y_trainvalid, y_trainvalid])` and `pd.concat([new_file_label, new_file_label])` to see if you have exactly the same issue. If not, your headers are different you need to rename them and retry to concatenate the both.

Comment: I edited the the command you told me, I'll try to concatenate the same archives to see if the same issue occurs

Comment: When I use both pd.concat([y_trainvalid, y_trainvalid]) and pd.concat([new_file_label, new_file_label]) they work normally, the problem only occurs when I concatenate y_trainvalid with new_file_label

Comment: Your headers are different … you have `int` and `string` types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y_trainvalid.columns = [str(x) for x in y_trainvalid.columns]
new_file_label.columns = [str(x) for x in new_file_label.columns]
y_trainvalid2 = pd.concat([y_trainvalid, new_file_label])
```